# inserting a string stored in variable to a command in shell?

Tags: linux, shell, grep, ls

I defined $A that has the value  A12 (for example ).
how do I pass that value to the location that has XXX in the command :

```
ls -dtr XXX_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | sort -n | tail -1
```

the `XXX_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` is actually a folder name format (a12_20130233)

is there a way to pass it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally it would be as simple as `$A` but because the following character (an underscore in this case) can be interpreted as part of the variable name, it needs to be delimited with `{}`, like so:

```
ls -dtr ${A}_[0-9]...
```